# Failed to retrieve tables from database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to open the database in SQL Server 2012. But it is showing the following error:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sft)
>
> Additional Information:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact_SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:701)

Any suggestion to resolve the problem ?

Comment: See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258732(v=sql.80).aspx - it explains the error and what you can do to solve it.

Comment: I tried in this way but it is not even letting me to open the properties option....

Comment: Usually when this kind of stuff happens I try to restart the server if possible

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when the engine gets an OutOfMemeory exception while trying to perform an action. There isn't much you can do about this programmaticly because you are bumping up against the physical constraints of the machine that is hosting the SQL Server instance. Look at your system statistics if you still have uncommitted memory chances are you just need to increase the memory pool limit of the SQL engine. You will need an account with admin privs to do this. I have also run into this issue where query's are getting blocked at the server and queuing up, after a certain point you run out of memory to do anything and you have to restart the server so it's probably worth it to check the jobs pane and make sure you don't have a bunch of queries in the WAIT state.